# Catch handler for multiple exceptions?

Tags: java, exception, error-handling

I am experimenting with exceptions and i want to ask when it is possible to handle multiple exceptions in one handler and when it is not?

For example i wrote the following code which combines two exceptions (*FileNotFoundException*  *OutOfMemoryError*) and the program runs properly without any error. Al thought the handling is not so relevant with the functionality of the code i chose them just to see when i can combine multiple exceptions in on handler :

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.lang.OutOfMemoryError;

public class exceptionTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int help = 5;

        try {
            foo(help);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException | OutOfMemoryError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static boolean foo(int var) throws Exception {
        if (var > 6)
            throw new Exception("You variable bigger than 6");
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

But when i choose different type of exceptions the compiler gives me error . For example when i choose IOException  and Exception i have the error the exception is already handled "   :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.Exception;



public class exceptionTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int help = 5;

        try {
            foo(help);
        } catch (IOException | Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static boolean foo(int var) throws Exception {
        if (var > 6)
            throw new Exception("You variable bigger than 6");
        else
            return true;
    }

}
```

So why is this happening ? Why in one occasion i can use multiple exception in handler and in the other not ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have your own class called `IOException`?

Comment: `OutOfMemoryError` belongs in the `java.lang.Error` hierarchy. Different than `java.lang.Exception`.


Take a look at the different classes:
[IOException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html)

&
[OutOfMemoryError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html)

Comment: have a look at http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/diagram-for-hierarchy-of-exception-classes/

Comment: [Your code works fine in both cases.](https://ideone.com/xM43Qy)

Comment: Sotirios i just import it from java.io.IOException

Comment: It's a warning, not an error.

Comment: Chris Tarazi , you mean base on your graph :http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/diagram-for-hierarchy-of-exception-classes/  that if the exceptions belong to the same hierachy  then there is a problem and when they belong in different there is no problem?

Comment: Works fine for me (JDK 1.7). No warning, no error. And, in fact, **both are subclasses of `Throwable`**.

Comment: I think your examples are swapped.

Comment: @ChrisTarazi The both extend `Throwable`.

Comment: Both compile and run fine for me with OpenJDK 7. No warnings or errors. What implementation are you using?

Comment: My apologies , Anubian Noob and Sotirios DElimanolis  was correct, i just changed the second code with  IOException and  Exception, and i have the message the error is already handled. That is what i noticed in first time

Comment: So why the problems is your exception is already handled ? Because they belong to the same hierarchy?

Comment: @Dioskouros I think the problem lies with `IOException` being a child of `Exception`. So there's no reason for you to handle a specific exception (IOException) and a broad exception (Exception) at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the message because `IOException` is a subclass of `Exception`. Therefore, if an `IOException` were thrown, it would be caught by a `catch (Exception e)` statement, so catching it as an `IOException` is redundant.
The first example works because neither `FileNotFoundException` nor `OutOfMemoryError` is a subclass the other.

However, you can catch sub-classed exceptions using the separate catch statement:

```
try{
    // code that might throw IOException or another Exception
} catch (IOException e) {
    // code here will execute if an IOException is thrown
} catch (Exception e) {
    // code here will execute with an Exception that is not an IOException
}
```

If you do this, please note that the subclass must come first.

Comment: Yes McLoving , now i understood why is the problem . Chris Tarazi already gave me the answer which explains it cleary " @Dioskouros I think the problem lies with IOException being a child of Exception. So there's no reason for you to handle a specific exception (IOException) and a broad exception (Exception) at the same time."  Thank you all guys for your comments and your interest !

Comment: You're welcome. There are a lot of complications when dealing with exceptions and inheritance.